# jQuery.ajax() gets parseError on fetching JSON from x-domain source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

This is my Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    "url": url,
    "dataType" : "json",
    "async" : false,
    "success" : function(e) {
        retval = e;
    },
    "complete" : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        debugger;
    },
    "error" : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    },
    "xhrFields": {
       withCredentials: true
    }
})
```

`url` is for example `http://api.justin.tv/api/channel/show/{0}.json` (`{0}` being replaced by a channel name)

The script breaks at error with textStatus "parseserror". Also I notice that `jqXHR` has no responseText, but instead all the json files I tried to load have appeared in the resources tab with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. Also I'm getting the warning `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.` for every ajax request. In addition, the x-domain requests doesn't seem to be asynchronous since code below the ajax call executes before the `error` callback executes.

So to clarify, my goal is for the ajax call success callback to run on every request with the parsed JSON object as `e`. This code already works for local json ajax calls, just not with the x-domain ones. The json returned by the x-domain calls is valid and shouldn't result in parsererrors.

If anyone has any ideas, please share

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to look into `jsonp` support in `$.ajax()` -- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You're violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), where you can't make XmlHttpRequests to domains outside of yours.  JSONP allows you to get around this.

I don't know if justin.tv supports JSONP; basically, it needs to wrap the response that it's sending you inside of the method that's provided by the JSONP call.

Answer (score 1):

try adding ?jsonp= to the end of your url. You usually need to specify a callback to get correct JSONP

```
> http://api.justin.tv/api/channel/show/{0}.json?jsonp=
```

See the difference between these two urls

http://api.justin.tv/api/channel/show/342.json?jsonp=

and

http://api.justin.tv/api/channel/show/342.json

?jsonp= adds parens around the data so you can use it cross domain.

Comment: Better: Set `dataType` to `jsonp` and add the option `jsonp: 'jsonp'`. See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/